# how to use function on Constructor, TodoList

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the results of the todolist action, from https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/javascript/todo-list.html
explain take it to use it just write it down

```
$('#my-todo-list').TodoList ({
   onCheck: function(checkbox) {
      console.log('check');
   },
   onUnCheck: function(checkbox) {
      console.log('un check');
   }
})
```

but the results of the action show nothing.

I tried to open the Constructor from the TodoList function,
and displays the following functions,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkiZW.png)

for that I tried writing

```
$('#my-todo-list').TodoList ({
     check: function check(item) {
          console.log('check');
     },
     unCheck: function unCheck(item) {
          console.log('unCheck');
     }
});
```

and still not display the results of these actions..

Comment: did you try this -> $(document).ready(function() { #your code# });

Comment: I've done it before..